# AWK: How to put field ($1) inside regular expression to select all prefixes?

Tags: text-processing, awk

Assume I have a file A:

```
fileA 
fileB
```

Suppose I have now a file named:

```
fileA_someprefix_20160101.txt
```

Now I want to *match all lines from A which prefix this `filename`*, so I thought:

```
FILE_NAME="fileA_someprefix_20160101.txt"    
awk '"$FILE_NAME" ~ /^$1/' A.txt
```

I tried different ways to escape the dollar sign, but it did not work.

In all examples the field is part of the expression (left) instead of the regex.

How do I a `reverse` start with?

Answer (score 1):

You can not refer `awk` variable inside regular expression `/regex/`.

If you want to check for prefix, POSIXly, use `index()` function instead:

```
FN="fileA_someprefix_20160101.txt" awk 'index(ENVIRON["FN"], $1) == 1' <file
```

From the [POSIX specs for `awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13):

> **index**(*s*, *t*)
>
> Return the position, in characters, numbering from 1, in string *s* where string *t* first occurs, or zero if it does not occur at all.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `ENVIRON` special array; thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using GNU awk, it allows a string expression to be on the right hand side of `~`.

```
awk -v FILE_NAME="$FILE_NAME" 'FILE_NAME ~ ("^" $1)'  A.txt
```